# A simple loop through URL's to display and traverse pages using "Previous" and "Next" buttons in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I would like to display a particular page in a web form, where hitting "Next Page" and "Previous Page" buttons display the previous or next page.
(details below):

To get to a particular page, you can adjust the page value after the slash at "Bitonal#page/" in my URL shown below. For example, you could get to page # 136 by going to:

http://br.mdsa.net/BookReader/index.html?id=ce425&item=1&format=Bitonal#page/136/mode/1up

Look at the slash after "Bitonal#page/"

This next number is the page number. Hence, the above URL is for page # 136. I want to be able to get to the next or previous page upon "Previous Page" or "Next Page" button click.

For instance, if I hit the previous button from the URL above, I want to be able to get to where "135" is the value after "Bitonal#page/" so that I can view page # 135.

What is the loop code so that I can provide this functionality to my buttons below?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to be a worthwile requirement. What didn't work?

Comment: I'm not seeing an actual question here.  Are you encountering any sort of issue with your implementation?  What do you need help with?

Comment: Sorry. Im a newbie. This is the first project I've ever worked on. I do not know how to loop through the URL's and apply to the next page and previous page buttons.

Comment: The pageviewer is the BookReader I am using to view pages 1 through 800 as described in the initial post. I simply want the loop code to link all 800 pages to to the "Next Page" and "Previous Page" buttons in order to display either the next page or previous page upon click by the user. This is probably a very newbie question but this is my first project, and I cant find out how to do this anywhere.

Comment: Maybe it's just me but I have never seen a pageviewer. Is it a control in the Visual Studio toolbox? or some other control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a module or class level variable to hold the page number; initially set to the first page:

```
    Dim pg As Integer = 1
```

in the next page button code do this:

```
pg += 1
Dim pgLink As String
pgLink = "http://br.mdsa.net/BookReader/index.html?id=ce425&item=1&format=Bitonal#page/" & pg & "/mode/1up"

'assign the pgLink to the pageviewer
```

in the previous page button code do the same except that the page gets subtracted:

```
If pg > 1 Then pg -= 1 
Dim pgLink As String
pgLink = "http://br.mdsa.net/BookReader/index.html?id=ce425&item=1&format=Bitonal#page/" & pg & "/mode/1up"

'assign the pgLink to the pageviewer
```

Comment: Bingo. I think everyone else wasn't taking it for the newbie question that it was. This is my first project. Thank you so much.